# Distance based Price Calculation in C#

Tags: c#

I have to calculate price based on distance and kilometer chunks. Can someone please help me to achieve the goal. My Array is as follow:

```
List<PriceStructure> priceStructure = new List<PriceStructure>()
{
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 1, ToKm = 10, Price = 90, IsMinimum = true, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 11, ToKm = 20, Price = 7, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 21, ToKm = 30, Price = 6, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 31, ToKm = 40, Price = 5, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 41, ToKm = 50, Price = 4, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 51, ToKm = 60, Price = 3, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 61, ToKm = 70, Price = 2, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 71, ToKm = 300, Price = 1.50M, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = false },
    new PriceStructure { FromKm = 301, ToKm = 0, Price = 0, IsMinimum = false, IsContact = true }
};
```

The minimum price is 90 if the distance is between 1 to 10 kilometers. If the distance is more than 10, then each kilometer will be calculated on Price defined in Array on each row on a per kilometer basis (starting from 11th Kilometer).

For Example:

- If Distance is 8 KM then Price would be 90
- If Distance is 15 KM then Price would be 90 + (5x7) = 90 + 35 = 125
- If Distance is 39 KM then Price would be 90 + (29x5) = 90 + 145 = 235
- If Distance is 63 KM then Price would be 90 + (53*2) = 90 + 106 = 196
- If Distance is more than 300 KM, then function should return to quote price.

Comment: You haven't explained where you're stuck, so I'm not quite sure what advice you need. I'd first select the `PriceStructure` object by ordering the list in descending order of `FromKm` and then select the first value smaller than the distance. You can then do your calculations based on that object.

Comment: I wouldn't use a `List<PriceStructure>` to represent this data. Can you change how a price structure is represented?

Comment: This data would be coming from Database Table, I am using here in ListView to explain only exactly according to DB Fields.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I copied your code and made a function that takes in a List & the distance:

```
public static decimal CaluclatePrice(int distance, List<PriceStructure> priceStructures)
{
    decimal minimumPrice = priceStructures.Find(p => p.IsMinimum == true).Price;
    PriceStructure ps = priceStructures.Find(p => distance >= p.FromKm && distance <= p.ToKm);

    if (ps.IsMinimum)
        return ps.Price;
    else
        return (distance - 10) * ps.Price  + minimumPrice;

}
```

Like mentioned in the other comment, you should rename the `PriceStructure.Price` variable to something like `PricePerKm` to prevent confusion or maybe have both `StartingPrice` & `PricePerKm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to reflect the calculations you've already done, something like:

```
int CalculatePrice(PriceStructure ps) {

    int distance = ps.ToKm - ps.FromKm;  

    if(distance < 10) {
       return 90;
    }

    int price = 90 + ((distance - 10) * ps.Price);

    return price;

}
```

Then you can iterate over `priceStructure` and call the function with each of the items from your list.

To improve the code you could perhaps treat the minimum distance as a constant or at least a variable. I'd also suggest renaming the `Price` property in PriceStructure to something which better represents what the value actually is, it sounds like `PricePerKm`

Comment: Quite possibly but this is not really a place to get people to write your business logic for you. Maybe take what you can from the concept and make it work for your use case

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like a good candidate for the Chain of Responsibility pattern.

The idea basically is that you have a linked list of handlers which in turn decide whether they can do the calculation or pass the task to the next handler in the chain.

You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

Now on the task at hand. I've created a simple example that should give you the main idea:

Here's how you should use the end API:

```
var calculator = new PriceCalculator();
calculator.RegisterNext(new CalculationHandler(0, 8, (dist) => 90M));
calculator.RegisterNext(new CalculationHandler(9, 15, (dist) => 125M));
calculator.RegisterNext(new CalculationHandler(16, 39, (dist) => 235M));
calculator.RegisterNext(new CalculationHandler(40, 63, (dist) => 196M));
calculator.RegisterNext(new CalculationHandler(64, int.MaxValue, (dist) => 1000));

var km = 29;
Console.WriteLine("Price for {0}km is: {1}", km, calculator.Calculate(km));
```

`PriceCalculator.cs`

```
public class PriceCalculator
{
    private ICalculatorHandler _handler;

    public PriceResult Calculate(int distance)
    {
        return _handler.Calculate(distance);
    }

    public void RegisterNext(ICalculatorHandler handler)
    {
        if (_handler == null)
        {
            _handler = handler;
        }
        else
        {
            _handler.RegisterNext(handler);
        }
    }
}
```

`ICalculationHandler.cs`

```
public interface ICalculatorHandler
{
    PriceResult Calculate(int distance);
    void RegisterNext(ICalculatorHandler handler);
}
```

`CalculationHandler.cs`

```
public class CalculationHandler : ICalculatorHandler
{
    private readonly int _minDist;
    private readonly int _maxDist;
    private readonly Func<int, decimal> _formula;
    private ICalculatorHandler _next;

    public CalculationHandler(int minDist, int maxDist, Func<int, decimal> formula)
    {
        _minDist = minDist;
        _maxDist = maxDist;
        _formula = formula;
        _next = null;
    }

    public PriceResult Calculate(int distance)
    {
        if (!(_minDist <= distance && distance <= _maxDist))
        {
            if(_next != null)
                return _next.Calculate(distance);

            return PriceResult.Invalid;
        }

        return new PriceResult(_formula(distance));
    }

    public void RegisterNext(ICalculatorHandler handler)
    {
        if (_next == null)
        {
            _next = handler;
        }
        else
        {
            _next.RegisterNext(handler);
        }
    }
}
```

`PriceResult.cs`

```
public class PriceResult
{
    public static PriceResult Invalid = new PriceResult(int.MaxValue);

    public decimal Value { get; }

    public PriceResult(decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

> Note: I am not aware of the context here but I advise you to do your data validations and null checks and not to use `decimal` as a general price type. My
> `PriceResult` class is a stub and I suspect yours should be way more
> polished. This code is just an example to get the main idea.

Comment: Your answer was hidden and i didnt see it. I am trying to implement it as it sounds really good brief process which might help me and lots of other developers as well. Bundle of Thanks.

Comment: The cool thing about this solution is that you can add or remove handlers at runtime. I don't know how often your pricing logic will change, however, since you mentioned that these fields are coming from a database, you can easily create handlers for each db row.